# How to Calculate Total Azure Artefact Size in Azure DevOps Server?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am planning a migration of our Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps in the cloud.

I am trying to determine the total size of Azure artefacts that we will need so that I can calculate the cost of moving to the cloud version.

But I am struggling to determine the total size of our current equivalent azure artefacts.

Note: I do not mean build artefact size, I mean azure artefact size

[image]

Do you know of a way of determining this in Azure Devops Server?

Thanks,

Comment: Based on my experience, the size of your build artifacts dont factor into billing. its...well...free or part of your pipeline cost. your question actually confused me because, we never got billed for artifacts and we have been using pipelines for years now.

Comment: Hi Jay. I am trying to calculate all the factors of our current usage in this calculator including how much space we will need for build artefacts. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Comment: the website page you are looking at is also what the community looks at too. there is that. further, since you are anyway a paying customer, why not contact azure sales. when I am setting up devops for my clients, they always want to know about price. and I always raise a billing request ticket and get all the specific prices.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the storage needed for Build artifacts, and the storage needed for Azure artifacts.

**Azure artifacts**

> Azure Artifacts is a service where you can create package feeds to publish and consume Maven, npm, NuGet, Python, and universal packages. Azure Artifacts is billed on a consumption basis, and is free up until 2 GB of storage. In the case that your organization needs more storage, you need to set up billing.

Source: [Start using Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts)

**Build artifacts**

> Or you can use build artifacts and pipeline artifacts to help store build outputs and intermediate files between build steps. You can then add onto, build, test, or even deploy those artifacts.

And now for the most important part of this answer:

> Q: Which artifacts count toward my total billed storage?
> A: Currently, the following get counted in your Azure Artifacts billed cost:
>
> - All packages (npm, NuGet, Python, Maven, and universal packages), including those packages stored from upstream sources
> - All symbols
>
> **You are not billed by Azure Artifacts for storage of Pipeline Artifacts, Build Artifacts, and Pipeline Caching.**

See the [Start using Azure Artifacts FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops#q-which-artifacts-count-toward-my-total-billed-storage)

Comment: Great, but I am still looking for how I can determine how much space I currently use for build artefacts before migrating

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the following query in your collection:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Buil' THEN 'Build'
WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Git/' THEN 'Git'
WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Dist' THEN 'DistributedTask'
ELSE Container 
END AS FileContainerOwner,
SUM(fm.CompressedLength) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS TotalSizeInMB
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(c.ArtifactUri, 13) AS Container,
fr.ResourceId,
ci.PartitionId
FROM tbl_Container c
INNER JOIN tbl_ContainerItem ci
ON c.ContainerId = ci.ContainerId
AND c.PartitionId = ci.PartitionId
INNER JOIN tbl_FileReference fr
ON ci.fileId = fr.fileId
AND ci.DataspaceId = fr.DataspaceId
AND ci.PartitionId = fr.PartitionId) c
INNER JOIN tbl_FileMetadata fm
ON fm.ResourceId = c.ResourceId
AND fm.PartitionId = c.PartitionId
GROUP BY c.Container
ORDER BY TotalSizeInMB DESC
```

You will get results like this:

[image]

The value of "Build" is the total Build Artefact Size in this collection.

Comment: Thank you, but what I apparently need isn't the Build Artefact size (my bad title I suppose) but the Azure artefact size